# Multiple Axios requests in lambda function

Tags: javascript, lambda, async-await, axios, get-request

I am trying to make a lambda function in JS that makes a Get request, in which the ids populate another Get request, through a for loop, for tracking information and then Post that information as a response.

I can console.log the for loop but it's not returning the values of the second Get request. Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    
    await axios.get("< TESTING SITE>", {
        auth: {
            username: "<un>",
            password: "<p>"
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++){ 
            axios.get(`https://testingsite.com/test/${res.data[i].id}`, config).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                    axios.put(`https://testingsite/${response.data[i].userId}`,
                    {
                        "statusId" : 1
                    })
                }
                })
        }
        return
    })
    .catch (error => {
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: error.response.status,
            body: {
                "error": error
            }
        });
        return;
    });
    return
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not returning the values of the second GET request"?

Comment: Unrelated: (1) Pick a convention for objects: use quotes or don't, don't do both, (2) skip superfluous returns, (3) pick a JS formatter or coding convention and use it for *all* the code.